# Use method from angular-google-maps agmCircle into typescript file

Tags: angular, google-maps

I want to get the bounds of a circle when it is changed. From here https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmCircle.html I can see it has a "getBounds" method, how can I access it from my typescript file to log this data? Currently my html circle component looks like this:

```
<agm-circle [latitude]="lat + 0.3" [longitude]="lng" 
      [radius]="10000"
      [fillColor]="'blue'"
      [circleDraggable]="true"
      [editable]="true"
      (dragEnd)="test($event)"
      >
  </agm-circle>
```

And I expect to have a function like this:

```
test(m){
   // get bounds from circle in some way
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as a `ViewChild` in your component

```
@ViewChild(AgmCircle) child;

test(m) {
    console.log(this.child.getBounds())
}
```